# Optimisation Problem on butter melting

Tags: derivatives, optimization

> The time in minutes ($t$) taken to melt 100 g of butter depends upon the percentage of the butter which is made of saturated fats ($p$) as in the following function: $$ t = \frac{p^2}{10000} + \frac{p}{100} + 2 $$  Find the maximum and the minimum times to melt 100 g of butter.  *[6 marks]*

From what I have calculated, I was not able to calculate the maximum value. I was able to calculate the minimum value but 
if we solve 
$t'=\frac{2p}{10000}+\frac{1}{100}$
then make it to be 0, and solve, then one would arrive at p=-50. which is only one answer, as opposed to two, which is necessary if you want both a min value and a max value. If using my deduction, then t=1.75, but the answer says that min. is 2 and max. is 4.

Please advise.

Comment: It is discouraged to expect your Readers to follow a link in order to learn what Question is being asked of them.  It is good to have your thoughts added to the problem, but the body should be edited to have a reasonably self-contained problem formulation.

Comment: Notice that your function is increasing. Maybe it doesn't have a local maximum, but what restrictions are there on the percent $p$? Using the restrictions on $p$, can you find a global maximum? Also, does it make sense to have $-50\%$ of your butter containing saturated fat?

Comment: The answer doesn't reflect real life butter. Use $k=p/100$ to get $t=k^2+k+2$. For butter, $k\in[0.6,0.9]$ approximately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky, but notice that t denotes time and p a percentage. Thus we have that t runs from 0 to infinity while p ranges from 0 to 100. Now when you take the deritive you find that it a critical point at p=-50, but can i have -50 percent of something? (thats a no). What is important here is you have that by plugging in a point to the right of -50 we have that the function is increasing on (-50, $\infty$) namely it is increasing from all values of p that range from [0,100]. As the function is increasing on this interval we have that the minimum value is when p=0 and the max value is when p=100. Plugging in you will then yield your answers.